# how to show column and area charts with different y axis with same category and same x axis in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

i want to show area chart and column chart with different y-axis but same x-axis and same category.

```
   $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Combination chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
    },
    labels: {
        items: [{
            html: 'Total fruit consumption',
            style: {
                left: '50px',
                top: '18px',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
            }
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'John',
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
    }, {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Average',
        data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
        center: [0, 80],
        size: 100,
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});
```

i want like this, here am showing example image only (https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6rnm.png )

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'top' and 'height' properties of the y axis to achieve this:

```
yAxis: [{
  height:100
},{
  top:110,
  height:75
}]
```

Examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/KMA55/5/
- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LHZ3E/5/